How do I vertically center the cells in specific columns of a table?
I would like the content of the first, third, and fourth columns to be vertically centered, but I can't seem to do it. I know I could have used Excel and done it in 3 minutes, but I want to learn LaTeX.
My code is below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{10cm}|c|c|}
    \hline
        Uzd. & Kritēriji & Punkti & Kognitīvie līmeņi \\ \hline
        1. & Izvēlās atbilstošo darbību ar kopām - 1 punkts & 1 & I\\ \hline
        2. & Nosaka relatīvo biežumu - 1 punkts & 1 &I \\ \hline
        3. & Nosaka varbūtību - 1 punkts & 1 &II \\ \hline
        4. & Izvēlās pretējo notikumu - 1 punkts & 1 &II \\ \hline
        5. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Skaidro jēdzienu - 1 punkts \\
            Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto \\vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav
        \end{tabular} & 2 & III\\
    \hline
        6. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli - 1 punkts \\
            Aprēķina prasīto - 1 punkts
        \end{tabular} & 2 &II \\
    \hline
        7. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli - 1 punkts \\
            Aprēķina prasīto - 1 punkts
        \end{tabular} & 2 &II \\
    \hline
        8. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Attēlo dotos lielumus ar Venna diagrammu - 1 punkts \\
            Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija slikts laiks - 1 punkts \\
            Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija labs laiks - 1 punkts \\
            Nosaka varbūtību - 1 punkts
        \end{tabular} & 5 &II-III\\
    \hline
        9. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Attēlo dotos ar grafu palīdzību (koka diagrammu) un apraksta\\ to - 1 punkts \\
            Aprēķina nosacīto varbūtību - 1 punkts
        \end{tabular} & 5 &II-III \\
    \hline
        10. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Nosaka mazo kubu skaitu - 1 punkts \\
            Nosaka varbūtību a gadījumā - 1 punkts \\
            Nosaka varbūtību b gadījumā - 1 punkts
        \end{tabular} & 5 &III-IV  \\
    \hline
        11. & 
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti\\ izvēlēti uz taisnes a, bet viens uz taisnes b - 2 punkti \\
            Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti\\ izvēlēti uz taisnes b, bet viens uz taisnes a - 2 punkti \\
            Nosaka kopējo trijstūru skaitu - 1 punkts \\
            Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto \\vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav \\
            Skaidro vai citādi parāda, kas ar katru darbību vai katrā solī tiek \\aprēķināts - ir/nav
        \end{tabular} & 5 &IV \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Sorry, I don't know how to add code so it doesn't look like a mess...

Hi, welcome. To markup code as code, select it and click the button marked {} above the input field (keyboard shortcut Ctrl + K).

The \begin{center} environment has no effect because the table exceeds the text width.

The graphicx and array packages are superfluous here, as they are not needed to make this code snippet compilable.

You can achieve by using the package multirow and the command \multirow

@EmanueleNardi columns not rows, please correct your edit to the title.

If you use \begin{tabular}[t] you force the tables to be top aligned. If you don't want them to be top aligned, don't add use the t option (or if you must use the optional argument, replace it with c to centre the tables):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|c|c|}
    \hline
        5. & 
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hsize}@{}}
            Skaidro jēdzienu - 1 punkts \\
            Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto\\
            vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav
        \end{tabular} & 2 & III\\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Or you could switch to the tabularray package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htpb]
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={|Q|X|Q|Q|},
      cells={valign=m}
    }
    \hline
        5. & 
            {
              Skaidro jēdzienu - 1 punkts \\
              Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto \\
              vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav
            } 
            & 2 & III\\ \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



I've recreated your table using the tabularray package, which provides significantly more versatility for your requirements. While I personally avoid using vertical lines in tables, the decision is entirely yours, as they often make the table look cluttered and harder to read.
I've also made a couple of enhancements:

Rows now include automatic numbering (thanks to @Pascal974 for the suggestion);
Point formatting is now centrally managed using the \Points command, which now correctly accounts for plurals in Latvian (thanks to @Mico for the correction).



Full code
% \documentclass[a4paper, varwidth=15cm, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[showframe, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}.}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Points}{ m }{%
    {\bfseries[#1~%
        \int_compare:nTF {#1 = 1}{punkts}{punkti}
    ]}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {@{} Q[c] X[l] Q[c] Q[c] @{}},
    cells = {valign=m},% vertically aligns in the middle every cell
    column{1,3-4} = {font=\ttfamily},% order is important here
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c},% don't switch order
    hline{1-2,Z} = {1pt},
    hline{3-Y} = {.5pt, lightgray},
    cell{2-Z}{1} = { cmd = {\mycnta} },% automatic counter
    % vlines = {.5pt, lightgray},% try it yourself, I don't advice it
}
    Uzd. & Kritēriji & Punkti & {Kognitīvie\\līmeņi} \\ 
    & Izvēlās atbilstošo darbību ar kopām & 1 & I \\ 
    & Nosaka relatīvo biežumu & 1 & I \\ 
    & Nosaka varbūtību & 1 & II \\ 
    & Izvēlās pretējo notikumu & 1 & II \\ 
    & { Skaidro jēdzienu \Points{1} \\
        Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto \\
        vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav } & 2 & III \\
    & { Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli \Points{1} \\
        Aprēķina prasīto \Points{1} } & 2 & II \\
    & { Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli \Points{1} \\
        Aprēķina prasīto \Points{1} } & 2 & II \\
    & { Attēlo dotos lielumus ar Venna diagrammu \Points{1} \\
        Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija slikts laiks \Points{1} \\
        Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija labs laiks \Points{1} \\
        Nosaka varbūtību \Points{1}} & 4 & II-III \\
    & { Attēlo dotos ar grafu palīdzību (koka diagrammu) un apraksta\\ to \Points{1} \\
        Aprēķina nosacīto varbūtību \Points{1} } & 5 & II-III \\
    & { Nosaka mazo kubu skaitu \Points{1} \\
        Nosaka varbūtību a gadījumā \Points{1} \\
        Nosaka varbūtību b gadījumā \Points{1} } & 3 & III-IV  \\
    & { Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti\\ izvēlēti uz taisnes a, bet viens uz taisnes b \Points{2} \\
        Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti\\ izvēlēti uz taisnes b, bet viens uz taisnes a \Points{2} \\
        Nosaka kopējo trijstūru skaitu \Points{1} \\
        Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto \\vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav \\
        Skaidro vai citādi parāda, kas ar katru darbību vai katrā solī tiek \\aprēķināts - ir/nav } & 5 & IV \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


The calculations on lines 8-9-10 are inconsistent; the score doesn’t add up correctly :/

@Emanuelle Nardi, I propose \UseTblrLibrary{counter} \newcounter{mycnta} \newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}.} and cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd={\mycnta}}

Good idea, I will implement it :)

I think that in Latvian, the plural of "punkts" is "punkti".

I'd use tabularx and no nested tabular: just help LaTeX to state points where lines must be broken and add ties for things that should not be broken across lines.
I use a devious trick in order to get the serial number aligned at the top.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newlength{\uzd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}

\settowidth{\uzd}{Uzd.}
\newcommand{\0}[1]{%
  &
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\uzd]{#1.}%
    \hspace{\dimeval{2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}}%
  }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|>{\raggedright}X|c|c|}
\hline
Uzd. & Kritēriji & Punkti & Kognitīvie līmeņi \\
\hline
\0{1}
Izvēlās atbilstošo darbību ar kopām - 1~punkts
  & 1 & I\\
\hline
\0{2}
Nosaka relatīvo biežumu - 1~punkts
  & 1 & I \\
\hline
\0{3}
Nosaka varbūtību - 1~punkts
  & 1 & II \\
\hline
\0{4}
Izvēlās pretējo notikumu - 1~punkts
  & 1 & II \\
\hline
\0{5}
Skaidro jēdzienu - 1~punkts \newline
Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto
vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav
  & 2 & III \\
\hline
\0{6}
Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli - 1~punkts \newline
Aprēķina prasīto - 1~punkts
  & 2 & II \\
\hline
\0{7}
Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli - 1~punkts \newline
Aprēķina prasīto - 1~punkts
  & 2 & II \\
\hline
\0{8}
Attēlo dotos lielumus ar Venna diagrammu - 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija slikts laiks - 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija labs laiks - 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka varbūtību - 1~punkts
  & 5 & II-III \\
\hline
\0{9}
Attēlo dotos ar grafu palīdzību (koka diagrammu) un apraksta~to - 1~punkts \newline
Aprēķina nosacīto varbūtību - 1~punkts
  & 5 & II-III \\
\hline
\0{10}
Nosaka mazo kubu skaitu - 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka varbūtību a gadījumā - 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka varbūtību b gadījumā - 1~punkts
  & 5 & III-IV  \\
\hline
\0{11}
Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti
izvēlēti uz taisnes a, bet viens uz taisnes b - 2~punkti \newline
Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti
izvēlēti uz taisnes b, bet viens uz taisnes a - 2~punkti \newline
Nosaka kopējo trijstūru skaitu - 1~punkts \newline
Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto
vispārpieņemtos terminus - ir/nav \newline
Skaidro vai citādi parāda, kas ar katru darbību vai katrā solī tiek
aprēķināts - ir/nav
  & 5 & IV \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


I'd suggest to use en-dashes -- instead of hyphens and a more open look, so that vertical centering becomes irrelevant.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c>{\raggedright}Xcc@{}}
\toprule
Uzd. & Kritēriji & Punkti & Kognitīvie līmeņi \\
\midrule
1. &
Izvēlās atbilstošo darbību ar kopām -- 1~punkts
  & 1 & I\\
\addlinespace
2. &
Nosaka relatīvo biežumu -- 1~punkts
  & 1 & I \\
\addlinespace
3. &
Nosaka varbūtību -- 1~punkts
  & 1 & II \\
\addlinespace
4. &
Izvēlās pretējo notikumu -- 1~punkts
  & 1 & II \\
\addlinespace
5. &
Skaidro jēdzienu -- 1~punkts \newline
Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto
vispārpieņemtos terminus -- ir/nav
  & 2 & III \\
\addlinespace
6. &
Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli -- 1~punkts \newline
Aprēķina prasīto -- 1~punkts
  & 2 & II \\
\addlinespace
7. &
Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli -- 1~punkts \newline
Aprēķina prasīto -- 1~punkts
  & 2 & II \\
\addlinespace
8. &
Attēlo dotos lielumus ar Venna diagrammu -- 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija slikts laiks -- 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija labs laiks -- 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka varbūtību -- 1~punkts
  & 5 & II--III \\
\addlinespace
9. &
Attēlo dotos ar grafu palīdzību (koka diagrammu) un apraksta~to -- 1~punkts \newline
Aprēķina nosacīto varbūtību -- 1~punkts
  & 5 & II--III \\
\addlinespace
10. &
Nosaka mazo kubu skaitu -- 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka varbūtību a gadījumā -- 1~punkts \newline
Nosaka varbūtību b gadījumā -- 1~punkts
  & 5 & III--IV  \\
\addlinespace
11. &
Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti
izvēlēti uz taisnes a, bet viens uz taisnes b -- 2~punkti \newline
Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi punkti
izvēlēti uz taisnes b, bet viens uz taisnes a -- 2~punkti \newline
Nosaka kopējo trijstūru skaitu -- 1~punkts \newline
Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto
vispārpieņemtos terminus -- ir/nav \newline
Skaidro vai citādi parāda, kas ar katru darbību vai katrā solī tiek
aprēķināts -- ir/nav
  & 5 & IV \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}



I recommend that you employ a tabularx environment instead of a tabular environment and use the package's X column type for column 2. That way, you can let LaTeX perform any needed line-breaking operations automatically. Using a tabularx environment also allows you to achieve vertical centering of the cell contents by issuing the instruction \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}. See the user guide of the tabularx package for more information on this subject.
Separately, I would also recommend that you give the table a much more open and inviting "look", by (a) getting rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules and (b) using the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package -- \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \addlinespace -- instead of the basic-LaTeX \hline macro for the few remaining horizontal rules.
Finally, I'd (a) introduce a line break in the header of column 4, to make the column's width a lot narrower, (b) disallow line breaks between numbers and "punkt[si]", (c) replace all simple dashes with en-dashes, and (d) load the fontenc package with the option T1 in case you compile your document with pdfLaTeX.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi

\usepackage[latvian]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % suppress full justification
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering

\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{} lLcc @{}} % or, if you prefer, '1\textwidth'
\toprule
Uzd. & Kritēriji & Punkti & Kognitīvie  \\ 
     &           &        & līmeņi \\
\midrule
1. & Izvēlās atbilstošo darbību ar kopām~-- 1~punkts & 1 & I\\ \addlinespace
2. & Nosaka relatīvo biežumu~-- 1~punkts & 1 &I \\ \addlinespace
3. & Nosaka varbūtību~-- 1~punkts & 1 &II \\ \addlinespace
4. & Izvēlās pretējo notikumu~-- 1~punkts & 1 &II \\ \addlinespace
5. & Skaidro jēdzienu~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto vispārpieņemtos terminus~-- ir/nav
   & 2 & III\\ \addlinespace
6. & Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Aprēķina prasīto~-- 1~punkts
   & 2 &II \\ \addlinespace
7. & Pamato atbilstošā savienojuma izvēli~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Aprēķina prasīto~-- 1~punkts
   & 2 &II \\ \addlinespace
8. & Attēlo dotos lielumus ar Venna diagrammu~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija slikts laiks~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Nosaka to dienu skaitu, kurās bija labs laiks~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Nosaka varbūtību~-- 1~punkts
   & 5 &II--III\\ \addlinespace
9. & Attēlo dotos ar grafu palīdzību (koka diagrammu) un apraksta to~-- 1~punkts \newline
     Aprēķina nosacīto varbūtību~-- 1~punkts
   & 5 &II--III \\ \addlinespace
10. & Nosaka mazo kubu skaitu~-- 1~punkts \newline
      Nosaka varbūtību a gadījumā~-- 1~punkts \newline
      Nosaka varbūtību b gadījumā~-- 1~punkts
    & 5 &III--IV  \\ \addlinespace
11. & Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi~punkti izvēlēti uz taisnes a, bet viens uz taisnes b~-- 2~punkti \newline
      Aprēķina iespējamo trijstūru skaitu gadījumā, kad divi~punkti izvēlēti uz taisnes b, bet viens uz taisnes a~-- 2~punkti \newline
      Nosaka kopējo trijstūru skaitu~-- 1~punkts \newline
      Skaidrojumā korekti pielieto matemātikas valodu, lieto vispārpieņemtos terminus~-- ir/nav \newline
      Skaidro vai citādi parāda, kas ar katru darbību vai katrā solī tiek aprēķināts~-- ir/nav
    & 5 &IV \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Just a slide error in your code: the line \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{} lLcc @{}} or, if you prefer, '1\textwidth' must be changed into \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{} lLcc @{}}% or, if you prefer, '1\textwidth' (the % was missing) otherwise compilation doesn´t work (lualatex)

@mario1000 - Thanks for pointing out that I'd missed a % (comment) character Fixed now.
